# Strenghtening internal neck muscles associated with head going back?

Tags: muscle-soreness, neck

I find tight longus colli vertical and sore platysma on my right side. I have tried to strenghten them by holding my head towards my hand forward/sideways but inefficient. The way I get them activated apparently is stretching my head back behind me that sounds unsafe.

**How can you strengthen the muscles here that require stretching head backwards?**

[image]

Comment: If I we're you, I'd seek the advice of a PT.

Comment: I agree with rrirower about getting professional guidance.  Your question is asking about rehab rather than fitness.  With a [concussion](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/concussion/basics/definition/con-20019272) and a neck injury, you may aggravate your symptoms without proper instruction.

Comment: http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/NeckWt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubber bands or a neck harness that you can attach a light plate to.

Answer (score -1):

1. Rubberband is probably the safest method
2. You can use the BJJ neck training [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlU8jytpTr4):

[image]